# How can I take off responsive from Bootstrap's navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap.
I have its navigation bar on top, and it shrinks if I narrow down browser's width.
I don't want it. How can I?

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
<div class="container-fluid">
            <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-target=".nav-collapse" data-toggle="collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </a>
.
.
.
```

Comment: Try using a `container` instead of a `container-fluid`.  I believe that the difference between the two is that one is response and one isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for this lies in the CSS for responsiveness (responsive.css?) 
Search for the

```
"container-fluid"
```

rule and disable it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `<div class="container">` instead of `<div class="container-fluid">`

for reference go through this [link](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#layouts)